# ASPxUploadControl Validation Error Message

Tags: asp.net, validation

I know this might be very old but I need to show an error based from my custom validation. I want the error to display just how  is displaying its error.

I'm hoping for something like

```
uploadControlId.ErrorText = "This is a custom error."
uploadControlId.ErrorShow = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but do you want something like this?

```
     public ActionResult Create(uploadControlId model)
    {

        if (model.uploadControlId == 0)//Whatever your condition is
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("YourModelPropertyName", "This is a  custom error");
        }
    }
```